# How to make WaitHandle.WaitAny NOT prioritize handles with smaller index?

Tags: .net, multithreading, waithandle

The [`WaitAny()` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z.aspx) say:

> If more than one object becomes signaled during the call, the return
>   value is the array index of **the signaled object with the smallest
>   index** value of all the signaled objects.

In other words, it will not treat the handles "fairly", i.e. choose the one signaling for the longest time (wishful thinking, I guess) or at least, just choosing a random signaled one, so that over time, fairness is at least provided statistically.

I can of course provide `WaitAny()` with a different permutation of my list of wait handles (round-robin or random) on every call:

```
public static int WaitAnyFair(this WaitHandle[] handles)
{
    return WaitHandle.WaitAny(Shuffle(handles));
}
```

But isn't there some smarter way to do this?

(Originally, I was checking if [`BlockingCollection.TryTakeFromAny()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs#8411347eebfd8252) methods are fair. As they are based on `WaitHandle.WaitAny`, they aren't fair either.)

Comment: No need to go to a 3rd party site to get .NET framework source code from decompiled sources, go right to [Microsoft's Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs#0c84922eea8bf511). As to the why it is not "fair", making it fair is slower than finding the first available. If I have a choice between fair and fast, I rather have fast be the default.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's awesome. Didn't know the sources are online as well. Only knew the zips for download. I updated the link in my question.

Comment: That changed around February of this year. The new site came up with the web interface.

Comment: Well, you can check the state of each handle after `WaitAny` has returned and decide how to proceed after you have all the information. Not sure if that would qualify as "smarter"; it certainly sounds like it would be the slowest.

Comment: @Jon it would be smarter. But how can I check the state of each handle? I could for `ManualResetEvent`s, but not for `AutoResetEvent`s.

Comment: @JimMischel `WaitAny` does return the index of the handle that signaled. It's just that waiting on an `AutoResetEvent` will reset it immediately after its signal was detected. Jon solution implied a 2nd check, i.e. `WaitOne`, **again** after `WaitAny`, which obviously is a problem for `AutoResetEvent`s.

Comment: My point (I inadvertently deleted my comment) is that if you put an `AutoResetEvent` in the array to be used for `WaitAny`, then there is no way you can tell if it was signaled, unless its index is the one returned. That's a problem in general, regardless of whether `WaitAny` is fair. The same goes for using `Mutex` or `Semaphore` wait handles: your thread ends up acquiring a `Mutex` or `Semaphore` *without your knowledge*. So the real solution is: don't use `AutoResetEvent`, `Mutex` or `Semaphore` wait handles in calls to `WaitAny`.

Comment: @JimMischel Are you suggesting that although `WaitAny` returns a single index, it might in fact have reset (in the case of `AutoResetEvent`s) other handles as well? That would be contrary to what I expected - and depending on the use case rather disappointing.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy: Indeed, with `AutoResetEvent`s that option is off the table.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy: Yes, that's what I'm implying. Documentation is unclear. For example, the remarks for [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) says: "The function modifies the state of some types of synchronization objects. Modification occurs only for the object or objects whose signaled state caused the function to return."

Comment: Although on further reflection, it does seem contrary to expectations.

Comment: Fairness is highly overrated.  It is already made *intentionally* unfair by the operating system.  Backgrounder [is here](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/12/14/anticonvoy-locks-in-windows-server-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/).

Comment: Why do you need fairness? All programs that rely on timing or scheduling for correctness are broken. So you cannot rely on it for correctness but maybe for performance.

Comment: @HansPassant @usr I'm not actually interested in *real* fairness - an illusionary concept in a non-deterministically scheduled multi-threading world anyway. On reflection, I probably should have called it something like **"How to make `WaitAny` NOT prioritize"**. Because in effect that's what it does. The first handle gets preferential treatment over the others. That might starve the rightmost handle significantly. But if Jim's caveat holds true, which I'll check, then I'll have to do it completely differently anyway.

Comment: Do the WaitOne (with a timeout of zero) *before* the WaitAny. If any WaitOne succeeds, then don't call WaitAny.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's perfect! Unless you make it a solution - which I'd accept - I'll make it one: 1. Randomized iteration over all handles using `WaitOne`. 2) `WaitAny` on all handles.

Comment: Go ahead and turn my suggestion into an answer then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be easy to implement without having to allocate arrays.

1. Manually call `handles[i].WaitOne(0)` over `i`, each time in a different order of iteration. Break at the first call that returns `true`
2. In case all `WaitOne()` calls returned `false`, do the `WaitAny(handles, timeout)`

Thanks @RaymondChen for the idea.

```
private static int _lastWaitAnyMoreFairStartIndex;

public static int WaitAnyMoreFair(WaitHandle[] handles, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    // increment, but prevent from wrapping negative,
    // as that would break the modulo indexing
    if (++_lastWaitAnyMoreFairStartIndex < 0)
        _lastWaitAnyMoreFairStartIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < handles.Length; i++)
    {
        var index = (i + _lastWaitAnyMoreFairStartIndex) % handles.Length;
        if (handles[index].WaitOne(0))
            return index;
    }

    return WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles, timeout);
}
```

N.B. My current use case is a single-thread consumer, I therefore did not bother to make it thread safe.